# How can I validate a complex model object in Spring 3 using @Valid annotations?

Tags: validation, spring-mvc, bean-validation

I have a model object modelling a purchase order. The purchase order has a few fields (such as ID and date) and a list of line-items as ArrayList. I can validate the parent purchase order ok, but it chokes when validating the line-items.

Can anyone help me with validation of complex objects? If I cannot validate complex objects auto-magically, how can I write a custom validator that relies upon the constraint annotations in the parent and then iterates over the child line-items? This Validator instance needs to be able to call `something.validate(purchaseOrder)` and (for each line-item) `something.validate(lineItem)`. Where do I get "something" from?

I have specified `<mvc:annotation-driven />` in `dispatcher-servlet`. I am not using `@InitBinder`. And I am using `@Valid` annotation for validation in controller's method like

```
    @RequestMapping(params="confirmPurchaseOrder")
    public String confirm(
            @ModelAttribute("purchaseOrder") @Valid PurchaseOrder purchaseOrder,
            BindingResult result,
            @RequestParam("account") String accountString,
            @RequestParam("division") String divisionString,
            Model model)
    {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return PURCHASE_ORDER_CREATE_VIEW;
        }
```

The domain classes look like this: -

```
public class PurchaseOrder implements Comparable<PurchaseOrder> {
    /** Based on GUID */
    private String id;

    /** SOP */
    @NotNull
    private Integer SOP;

    /** Reference from client */
    @NotBlank
    private String purchaseOrderReference;

    /** PO date */
    @DateTimeFormat(style="S-")
    @NotNull
    private Date date;

    @Valid
    private final Collection<LineItem> lineItems = new ArrayList<LineItem>();
```

And

```
public class LineItem {
    ...Elided

    /** Generated from GUID */
    private String id;

    @NotNull
    @DateTimeFormat(style="S-")
    @Future
    private Date expiry;

    private String softwareVersion;

    @NotNull
    @NumberFormat(style = Style.NUMBER)
    @Min(1)
    private Integer licenceCount;
```

When committing a Purchase Order with an empty expiry date, I get the following exception:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException: Invalid property 'lineItems[]' of bean class [com.nit.ols.domain.PurchaseOrder]: Invalid index in property path 'lineItems[]'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:730)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:634)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `PurchaseOrder` class, try changing your `lineItems` collection to a `List`.  It looks like you are having the same problem addressed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5724976/hibernate-jsr303-validation-and-incorrectly-generated-propertypath) question.

Comment: Thanks David, the @Valid on the "List" works fine. Presumably it needs a list iterator.

Answer (score 1):

It's like David said, declaring `lineItems` of type `List` should do the trick. In Hibernate Validator 4.2.0 CR1 (not yet released atm, you could use the latest snapshot build if you are interested) also `Collection` should work, see [HV-468](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HV-468) for more details.